# Content type check for downloading a pdf in java gone wrong

Tags: java, pdf, get

I'm trying to post a request to download a pdf file in java.
I'm using - trying to fix cause the method is changed - someone else's code and, for what I've seen, before requesting the pdf file via a web service, a check for the content type is made. If the content-type requested is ok, then a call to the service to download the pdf file is made.

This is the method that checks for the content type:

```
public boolean checkContentType(String serviceName, Map<String, String> params, String contentType) {


    params.put(PARAM_SERVICE, serviceName);     

    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("checkContentType for serviceName: " + serviceName + " - Params: " + params + " - contentType: " + contentType);
    }

    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
    GetMethod get = new GetMethod(basicUrl);       
    get.setQueryString(ParameterUtil.getValuePairs(params));     
    log.info(get.getQueryString());
    try {
        httpclient.executeMethod(get);                      
        if (get.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {                     
            String respContentType = get.getResponseHeader("Content-Type").getValue(); 
            log.info("Request Content type [" +contentType + "] is not in response content type: [" + respContentType + "]");
            log.info(String.valueOf(contentType != null));
            log.info(String.valueOf(StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(respContentType, contentType)));
            return contentType != null && StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(respContentType, contentType);
        } else {
            log.error("Response status code KO: [" + get.getStatusCode() +"] from url: " + basicUrl + " with querystring: " + get.getQueryString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        log.error("Unable to get http response from url: " + basicUrl + " with querystring: " + get.getQueryString() + ". Ex Msg:" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        get.releaseConnection();
    }

    return false;
}
```

When Content-type is 'pdf' I get false on the second condition, but how do I know what Content-type should be set? I get this log: `Request Content type [pdf] is not in response content type: [text/plain;charset=UTF-8]`.

I've also tried to skip the content type check and go request the pdf immediately, but after waiting for some time I get a 16 kb pdf that I can't open. I've tried to set the content type to text/plain;charset=UTF-8 but I still get that log.

Shouldn't it be PDF since I'm downloading a pdf, or should I set somewhere in the code that I expect a pdf content type?

Answer (score 0):

Content type for pdf in http is "application/pdf" - You should check it for this content type in your code.

now looking at your output- Looks like server gave you "text/plain" content type- So in this case you will get false as outcome of this service.

Try to identify the server url which will give you content type as "application/pdf" OR set params(query string) which will give you pdf file to test your code.